# All PHP drop down list items appearing as "array"

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

My code is simply intending to populate two drop down lists with the names of teams and use the users selections to manipulate the points value of those teams. As a trivial example, pick 2 teams and add both their corresponding scores together.

My main problem is trying to get both the users team selection and the corresponding points stored in variables so I can use them. I'm not very familiar with using arrays or how to retreive the value I want. 
I can retrieve just the name easily but when I try to retrieve both points and names it populates the ddl incorrectly with "array" in every position. (It's hosted online here:

My code is below, I'm not sure if the problem is with how I'm creating my drop down list or how I'm retrieving the data.

Thanks for your help

```
<?
require_once 'login.php';
 $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
 if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($db_database)
 or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

 $sql="SELECT team, points FROM teams";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

 $options="";

 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {        
$team[$row["team"]]=$row["points"];  
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$team\">".$team. '</OPTION>';        
 }


 if (isset($_POST['teamA'])) $teamA = $_POST['teamA'];
 else $teamA = "(Not entered)";
 if (isset($_POST['teamB'])) $teamB = $_POST['teamB'];
 else $teamB = "(Not entered)";

 $teamA = htmlspecialchars($teamA);
 $teamB = htmlspecialchars($teamB);

 ?>
 <body>
 You picked <?php echo $teamA; ?>(with <?php echo $team[$teamA]; ?> points) 
 and <?php echo $teamB; ?>(with <?php echo $team[$teamB]; ?>) 
 </br>

 <form method="post" action="ddl.php">

 Team A: 
 <SELECT NAME=teamA>
 <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose
 <?=$options?>
 </SELECT>

 Team B:
 <SELECT NAME=teamB>
  <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose
  <?=$options?>
  </SELECT>

  <input type="submit" />

  </form>
   </body>
```

Comment: That's because it is an array instead of some scalar value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are building your SELECT list. The correct code would be something like this:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {        
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"{$row['team']}\">".htmlspecialchars($row['team']).'</OPTION>';        
}
```

You don't need to use `$team` variable.